# Populating a model from csv: __init__ arguments error

Tags: python, database, sqlalchemy, flask

I have a table with large number of columns which needs to be populated from a csv file. I have the following `__init__` code inside the model definition. [[1]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11905148/typeerror-init-takes-exactly-1-argument-3-given-pyxml)

```
class Table

    column1 = ............
    column2 = .............
    .......

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
            self.__dict__.update(kwargs)
```

The code to read from csv file is (load_csv.py)

```
data_file = "data.csv"
csv_file = csv.DictReader(open(data_file, 'rU'), delimiter=',')
for row in csv_file:
        table_entries = {}
        for key, value in row.items():
                table_entries[key] = value
        table_row = Table(table_entries)
        db.session.add(table_row)
        db.session.commit()
```

I get the following error on executing load_csv.py

```
    table_row = Table(table_entries)
TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)
```

I read [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11905148/typeerror-init-takes-exactly-1-argument-3-given-pyxml) this is because it is using the default `__init__` but I am not able to see why it is missing `__init__` function I have defined in code. Any help in resolving this problem would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to apply the dictionary as keyword arguments:

```
table_row = Table(**table_entries)
```

or change your `Table()` class to receive one argument:

```
class Table

    def __init__(self, row):
            self.__dict__.update(row)
```