# __init__() takes 3 positional arguments but 4 were given

Tags: python, class, object, inheritance, constructor

```
class Patient(object):
    '''
    Attributes
    name = Patient name
    age = Patient age
    conditions = Existing patient's conditions
    '''
    status='patient'#-----------class variable-------
    def __init__(self,name,age):
        self.name=name
        self.age=age
        self.conditions=[]
    def get_details(self):
        print(f'Patient record: {self.name}, {self.age} years.'\
              f'Current information: {self.conditions}.')
    def add_info(self,information):
        self.conditions.append(information)    
x=Patient('Yash',21)    
y=Patient('Raj',19)        

class Infant(Patient):

    def __init__(self,name,age):
        self.vaccinations=[]
        super().__init__(self,name,age)

    def add_vac(self,vaccine):
        self.vaccinations.append(vaccine)

    def get_details(self):
        print(f'Patient record: {self.name}, {self.age} years.'\
              f'Patient has had {self.vaccinations} vaccines.'\
              f'Current information: {self.codition}.'\
              f'\n{self.name} IS AN INFACT, HAS HE HAD ALL HIS CHEAKS?')

ash=Infant('Yash',21)

ash.add_vac('MMR')

print(ash.get_details())
```

Comment: Please repeat the intro tour; focus on [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Please add description as to what you're actually asking.

Comment: Don't pass `self` to `super().__init__()`

Comment: Your immediate problem is exactly what the message tells you.  Remember that `self` is an implied argument when you call a class method.

Comment: You could try using: `super(Infant, self).__init__(name, age)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [\_\_init\_\_() takes from 1 to 3 positional arguments but 4 were given](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20209415/init-takes-from-1-to-3-positional-arguments-but-4-were-given)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class Patient(object):
    '''
    Attributes
    name = Patient name
    age = Patient age
    conditions = Existing patient's conditions
    '''
    status='patient'#-----------class variable-------
    def __init__(self,name,age):
        self.name=name
        self.age=age
        self.conditions=[]
    def get_details(self):
        print(f'Patient record: {self.name}, {self.age} years.'\
              f'Current information: {self.conditions}.')
    def add_info(self,information):
        self.conditions.append(information)

x=Patient('Yash',21)    
y=Patient('Raj',19)

class Infant(Patient):

    def __init__(self,name,age):
        self.vaccinations=[]
        super().__init__(name,age);

    def add_vac(self,vaccine):
        self.vaccinations.append(vaccine)

    def get_details(self):
        print(f'Patient record: {self.name}, {self.age} years.\
                Patient has had {self.vaccinations} vaccines.\
                Current information: {self.conditions}.\
                {self.name} IS AN INFACT, HAS HE HAD ALL HIS CHEAKS?')

ash=Infant('Yash',21)

ash.add_vac('MMR')

print(ash.get_details())
```

this is only for ash instance ok, x, y is another instance.

Comment: Please do not just code dump as an answer. Explain how this code answers the question and why.

Comment: so you don't need to pass the self parameter(in any class function super().__init__(self, name, age)), and second, you can not use f string format multiple times in single string(in get_details function). and  you can find out your question's answer by comparing bothe programs

Comment: Please read [answer] for more details on how to answer questions on SO